# How do I copy a CGBitmapcontext?

Tags: objective-c, bitmap, core-graphics

I'm trying to save a bitmap context and assigning it to another bitmap context to be able to draw it later on. But i'm not 100 % sure how to do this. Is it possible to just assign it like the example below?

```
//paint.h

CGContextRef cachecontext;
CGContextRef cachecontexttoSaveOn;

//paint.m

-(void)copybitmap{
cachecontexttoSaveOn = cachecontext;
}


  - (BOOL) initContext:(CGSize)size {

            scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
             // scaleFactor = 1;
            //non-retina
            // scalefactor = 2; retina

            int bitmapBytesPerRow;

            // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
            // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
            // alpha.
            bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4*scaleFactor);
            bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * (size.height*scaleFactor));

            // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
            // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
            cacheBitmap = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
            smallbyte = 100 * 4*scaleFactor * 100 *scaleFactor;
            copiedBitmap = malloc(smallbyte);
            if (cacheBitmap == NULL){
                return NO;
            }

            CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little;
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

            cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (cacheBitmap, size.width*scaleFactor, size.height *scaleFactor, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

               CGContextScaleCTM(cacheContext, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

          CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cacheContext, 0, 0, 0, 0.0);
           CGContextFillRect(cacheContext, (CGRect){CGPointZero, CGSizeMake(size.height*scaleFactor, size.width*scaleFactor)});

        //    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
            return YES;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are not copying the context, but simply creating a new reference to it, so after **copybitmap** both variables will point to the same object and any change to one will affect the other...

Unfortunately there's no direct way to copy a CGBitmapContext into another one, so you'll need to manually create a second one with the same parameters as the first, and a copy of the backing data with memcpy (directly from your *cacheBitmap* if you have a reference to it, or getting it from **CGBitmapContextGetData**

Comment: Okey, I just realised, shouldn't it be enough with just coping the backing data and then assign it back to the original backing data when needed using memcpy?

Comment: Sure, CGBitmapContext simply holds a pointer to it's backing data, but you can change that data however you want, including overriding it with different content

Comment: Okey then i have a follow up question; Say I want to only save a part of the bitmap (100x100 for example). Is it faster to use memcpy to save the whole bitmap rather then looping through all 10 000 pixels using a for loop?

Comment: If your original data had the same width as the scaled one, you could use memcpy (with a smaller size) to copy it, but if the width is smaller you can't, because you'll need to copy the first 100*4 bytes, then skip the rest of the row (originalWidth - 100) * 4, then copy the second row and so on. You could mix both things and having a for loop and do a memcpy of 400 bytes for each rows. Just be careful in that case to assign the smaller data to a context that's properly setup with a correct size or weird stuff will happen